# How webdriver version is used in protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have chrome 80 installed in my system.

**webdriver manager version:**

```
webdriver-manager 12.1.7
```

**webdriver status:**

[image]

**Protractor version:**

```
Version 5.4.2
```

**Issue:**

This configuration works fine in local system but when I run in the ci/cd with the same configuration and versions. I get the below error:

```
Error: SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 78
  (Driver info: chromedriver=78.0.3904.11
```

Could someone let me know how protractor decides which version to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a web driver module inside the protractor installation, and I had to update it using the below command.

```
node node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\bin\webdriver-manager clean

node node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\bin\webdriver-manager update
```

Now my scripts works with lates driver.